# Specify special build and install order with requirements.txt for pip installs on Azure functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, pycocotools

For a Python based Azure function I need to specify the dependencies using `requirements.txt`.

```
albumentations==1.2.0
certifi==2022.6.15
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
cycler==0.11.0
Cython==0.29.30
fonttools==4.33.3
idna==3.3
imageio==2.19.3
joblib==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.4.3
matplotlib==3.5.2
networkx==2.8.4
numpy==1.22.4
opencv-contrib-python==4.6.0.66
opencv-python==4.6.0.66
packaging==21.3
Pillow==9.1.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
PyWavelets==1.3.0
PyYAML==6.0
qudida==0.0.4
requests==2.28.0
scikit-image==0.18.3
scikit-learn==1.1.1
scipy==1.8.1
six==1.16.0
threadpoolctl==3.1.0
tifffile==2022.5.4
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
torch
torchaudio
torchvision
typing-extensions==4.2.0
urllib3==1.26.9
setuptools
pycocotools@git+https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git@cocodataset-master#subdirectory=PythonAPI
```

When `setuptools` is installed already, then this works. But when setuptools is not installed, the build of `pycocotools` fails. How can the `requirements.txt` file be designed so that this task succeeds?
I dont want to use some external commands which parse the requrements.txt file and call pip with each individual package, as this is not possible on Azure as far as I understand (No Azure guy, just need to provide some Python code for Azure).

Can this be done, and if so, how?